# django- TypeError uploading csv file, invalid file

Tags: python, django, csv

On my django form wizard I added a file field to upload a csv file. In the get_context_data I am trying to process some of the information contained in the file.

I can print out `(self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')['file'])` and it returns an object. But when I try to open it using
    `file = open(self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')['file'], "rb")`
It returns this error:
`TypeError at /research/lists/1/import/
invalid file: <UploadedFile: SalesJan2009.csv (application/vnd.ms-excel)>`

Is there a Mime type issue here? Is there a way to change the Mime type after the file is uploaded?

Comment: could you post the value of `self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')['file']`?

Comment: I uploaded Book1.csv and what was printed out was "Book1.csv"

Comment: `csv` files are not binary, so you should open the file as "r" instead of "rb"

Comment: I changed my code to file = open(self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')['file'], 'r') and am still getting the same error, invalid file: <UploadedFile: Book1.csv (application/vnd.ms-excel)>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access uploaded files through `cleaned_data`. See the [documentation](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wizard.html#handling-files) on how to use uploaded files with a `FormWizard`.

> To handle `FileField` within any step form of the wizard, you have to add a `file_storage` to your `WizardView` subclass.
>
> This storage will temporarily store the uploaded files for the wizard. The `file_storage` attribute should be a `Storage` subclass.

Once you've set this up the `WizardView` class has a `get_form_step_files` method which will let you get the uploaded files.